# Allocate the same CPU resources to minimized Chrome as if it were maximized

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, cpu-usage

I am a chrome extension developer and struggle with the problem that my automation tools are not working properly when the chrome window is minimized.
I tried a lot of different things like using WebWorker API to make the timers run on a seperate thread and not be affected by the chromes timer throttling.
Unfortunately I think its not really my extensions fault, its the way chrome saves CPU resources and slows down minimized/inactive browsers.

Is there any tool for Windows that allows me to have a programm/browser act as if it would be open but its actually minimized/not visible?

I need to run 50+ browser windows at once and they don't fit all on my screen, of course I could just buy myself more monitors but I can't believe that there is no way to fix this problem on windows.

I heard that Chrome just behaves that way and that there is not really much you can do about it. But maybe there are Windows programms that make Chrome think its maximized but its actually hidden? (no need to be minimized, can be open on another TaskView Desktop)

The main problem is no matter if the Browser is on a seperate desktop, maximized in background (hidden behind another application) or minimized, it just doesn't work as efficient as it would be if the browser is visible on the screen.

Weird thing is I can even overlap the browser windows and it works, so as long as you can see 0.1% of the window its running perfectly fine...

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that does not involve minimizing Chrome or hacking it
would be to move it to another virtual desktop, so it's out of the way
but not minimized.

You may easily move windows between virtual desktops using the
Task View.

Third-party solutions also exist for moving windows via hotkeys.

References :

- [Multiple desktops in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/multiple-desktops-in-windows-36f52e38-5b4a-557b-2ff9-e1a60c976434)
- [How to use multiple desktops in Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-multiple-desktops-windows-10)
- [AUTOHOTKEY | WinMove | Virtual Desktop of choice](https://superuser.com/questions/1376182/autohotkey-winmove-virtual-desktop-of-choice)

Comment: Yes I was talking about that approach in my question.
Even when the browser is on another virtual desktop it doesn't work on full speed.
As soon as I move away from that virtual desktop it slows down again

Comment: I didn't understand that from the question, sorry. Is in *Start > Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows > Advanced* the "best performance" is set to "Background services"?

Comment: Yes it's set to "Background services"

Comment: Another possibility is [timer throttling](https://www.reddit.com/r/incremental_games/comments/jefviz/fyi_how_to_disable_timer_throttling_on_google/).

Comment: Yes I developed my extension using WebWorker API so I am not affected by timer throttling anymore.
The website where I do that animation has to load new elements for me to perform actions on it.
Seems like new elements are not getting loaded as quickly when the browser is in the background.
Thats why I think me as a extension dev can't really do anything to fix it.

Comment: Does it happen with Edge or Chromium?

Comment: It happens to Chromium

Comment: This reaches the point that requires knowledge that only you can have. You might need to find which part of your extension is impacted. For example, if it has some connection with DOM elements, you may keep your stuff out of the DOM. Going further with the question is impossible for me.